# Need to insert single record into the audit table after trigger is called

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE trg_demo 
(
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_trg_demo PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE trg_audit_sq;

CREATE TABLE trg_audit 
(
    a_id           NUMBER(10),
    modified_date  TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT pk_trg_audit PRIMARY KEY (a_id)
);
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON trg_demo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trg_audit 
    VALUES (trg_audit_sq.nextval, current_timestamp);
END;
```

```
INSERT INTO trg_demo VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO trg_demo VALUES (2, 'B');
```

Expected output:

```
+------+---------------+
| A_ID | MODIFIED_DATE |
+------+---------------+
|    1 | 16-12-21      |
+------+---------------+
```

I am going to insert rows into the `trg_demo` table once in 2 days. So, suppose today if I am inserting 2 rows then in `trg_audit` table, it will insert only one row with today's date and then after 2 days if I insert 4 rows into the `trg_demo` table then in `trg_audit` it will have a second row with A_ID as 2 and date as `18-12-21`.

Comment: What errors do you have in `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'trigger_trg'`?

Comment: Your code is just fine. i suspect it may be some kind of grant/permission problem. Check if your trigger is compiled correctly. Error says that its invalid

Comment: @AliFidanli Thanks there was an error in the trigger. But I could see two rows got inserted into the audit table but I need only one record to be inserted as shown in the original question

Comment: As you created a row-level trigger (FOR EACH ROW, right?), it fires for every INSERT statement you run. If you ran two inserts, two rows are being inserted into the log table. That's expected, you wrote it that way. Maybe you'd want to switch to a statement-level trigger.

Comment: @LittlefootThanks for the suggestion. How to do statement-level trigger?

Comment: @Vicky do you want trigger to insert only one row for a day ?

Comment: @AliFidanli Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use condition inside trigger to prevent the rest and accepts only one record  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON trg_demo
FOR EACH ROW
  declare 
flag number;
BEGIN

select count(*) into flag from trg_audit d where trunc(d.modified_date) = trunc(sysdate) ;

if flag < 1 then 
    INSERT INTO trg_audit
    VALUES (trg_audit_sq.nextval, current_timestamp);
    end if ;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround but how this will work If I insert the records into ```trg_demo``` because it is checking ```flag<1``` then next time flag count would be 2 then how that insert will happen in ```trg_audit```

Comment: flag will be 0 every day , because it will check trg_audit table if it has records for current day. then it will insert if no records exist yet

Comment: @vicky you may want to consider using an IDENTITY column instead of a sequence as that's one less object you need in the DB and you can remove the sequence.nextval from your code. seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
Every table I design I use this to uniquely identify a single row. Note it can be a PRIMARY KEY but doesn't have too.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that while the trigger can add the data into the audit table, please make sure to 2 updates to the trigger being used -

1. Use statement level trigger if you want 1 row to be inserted per data load into the table to avoid duplicate audit details.
2. Use AFTER insert when possible since the true way of knowing whether the insert has happened or not is to trigger it AFTER the insert, just in case the insert actually failed due to data constraint requirements, UNLESS, your requirement is to track evert insert attempt on the specific table.

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customers_credit_trg

   ```
         AFTER INSERT ON trg_demo

            FOR EACH ROW

             BEGIN

             INSERT INTO trg_audit VALUES (trg_audit_sq.nextval, 
               current_timestamp);

        END;
   ```